# How to use less memory when storing data locally and then displaying it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-storage

I am trying to fix an old website error and it crashes because it runs out of memory. The reason it runs out of memory is that we are storing the data locally then displaying it. I want to make these statements use less memory. How do I do that?

`localStorage.setItem("levels", JSON.stringify(__levels));`

`localStorage.setItem("rooms", JSON.stringify(__rooms));`

`var proj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("levels"));`

`var rooms = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rooms"));`

Comment: Why do you stringify the object? Why not directly?

Comment: localStorage only accepts string

Comment: Hmm... How big that object?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we call "the code pushing back". If you're hitting against memory issues or browser-storage limits, you're probably dealing with too much data for it to make sense for you to store in client-based storage, and the system requirements are pushing back against what you think your requirements are. You *could* look at other ways to have smaller serialized data (if it's storage limits); you *could* look at faster and more efficient serialization / deserialization (if it's memory limits). It sounds, however, like you should either be rethinking your decision to store it on the client in the way that you are or reconsidering the amount of data and trying to limit it to a subset of *required* data.